# How to delete an app from device using iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, macbook-pro

How do you delete (not just hide) an app? The Facebook app is corrupted and is causing my phone to crash and restart. (4 times just yesterday!) I really don't want to have to restore my entire phone, losing everything on it. It would be much easier if I could delete the app and re-download a version that is not corrupted.

In the past we could do this, but with this latest version of iTunes, I can't figure out how to!

Answer (score 4):

Why are you trying to do this via iTunes? You should delete the app on the phone and use the app store on the phone to re-download it.

However if you feel you must do this via iTunes after you have deleted the app from the phone, go to:

```
~/Music/iTunes/Mobile Applications
```

…and delete the application from there.

You can then download it again via the iTunes store and re-synch the phone.

Comment: My logic is this: If I simply delete the app from my iPhone and re-dowload via the app store, it knows that I have already downloaded it and it will simply put the same corrupted mess back onto my phone. I've already deleted it from my phone, and when I went to the app store, there was a cloud icon with a down arrow as the option next to the app, where the FREE button should be when downloading a new app.  This is why I thought it was going to download from iCloud - the currupted version, rather than a new version.

Comment: Nope! The cloud means it downloads a copy from iTunes not from your backup, the cloud item just means you have already purchased it and you dont have to re-purchase it

Answer (score 4):

You can delete an app from iTunes by going to the Apps section (from the dropdown on the left), then hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key. When it asks if you would like to keep the file or move it to trash, choose to move it to the trash.

You can also delete the app directly on the phone and download it through WiFi. Tap and hold the app's icon until it jiggles, then tap on the x to delete it. Next go to the App Store and install the app afresh.

Answer (score 2):

Open iTunes. At the top left of your window, there is a drop down menu, make sure it is set to **Apps**. You should now see all of your apps in icon form. The tabs below the player window allow you to switch into List view as seen below.

[image]

Then select the apps you want to delete, right click and select **Delete**.

[image]